# Несколько Select на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

имеется несколько select обернутых в div на странице, необходимо чтобы при выборе внутри рядом стоящего div отображалась информация...
Долго не думая написал вот так...
Проблема в том, что .change срабатывает только у первого div с select, а таких много.
Может неправильно скрипт написал?

```
  <select class="custom-select" id="select-names">
        <option value="22">Миша</option>
  </select>

  <div class="tab-content" id="names-info-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-22">
        <a class="text-dark" href="#">Мишка</a>
        <small class="text-muted">Очень хороший</small>
  </div>
  </div>

<script>
$('#names-info-content > div:first-child').addClass('active')


$('#select-names').change(function () {
    dropdown = $('#select-names').val();
    $('#' + "tab-" + dropdown).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');         
});
</script>
```

Comment: если несколько, значит, работать надо не с id элемента, а дать им одинаковый класс, и обработчик прикреплять к классу, а не id

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#names-info-content > div:first-child').addClass('active')


$('#select-names').change(function() {
  let dropdown = $(this).val();
  $('#' + "tab-" + dropdown).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select" id="select-names">
  <option value="22">Миша</option>
  <option value="23">Петя</option>
  <option value="24">Вася</option>
</select>

<div class="tab-content" id="names-info-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-22">
    <a class="text-dark" href="#">Мишка</a>
    <small class="text-muted">Очень хороший</small>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-23">
    <a class="text-dark" href="#">Петя</a>
    <small class="text-muted">Нормальный</small>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-24">
    <a class="text-dark" href="#">Вася</a>
    <small class="text-muted">Потянет</small>
  </div>
</div>
```